# Validate Australian DVA numbers (which may have variable length)

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match, variable-length

I'm doing validation on Australian DVA numbers, the rules are:

1. String length should be 8 or 9
2. First char should be N, V, Q, W, S or T
3. The next part should be letters or space and can have up to 3 characters
4. Next part should be number and can have up to 6 number
5. If the string length is 9 then last char is a letter, if 8 then it must be a number // This is the tricky part

Here is my current attempt and it's working fine:

```
if (strlen($value) == 9 && preg_match("/^[NVQWST][A-Z\s]{1,3}[0-9]{1,6}[A-Z]$/", $value)) {
    return true;
}
if (strlen($value) == 8 && preg_match("/^[NVQWST][A-Z\s]{1,3}[0-9]{1,6}$/", $value)) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

My question: Is there any way that I can combine these conditions in 1 regex check?

Comment: `[A-Z\s]{1,3}` must be `[A-Z]{1,3}`, right? You say, those must be letters only.

Comment: You might be able to achieve it using a lookahead. `^.{8}[A-Z]?$`

Comment: @bassxzero That doesn't make the optional letter dependent on the total length.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: sorry, letters and space, I'll fix my question

Comment: @catcon I just got an UV on my answer.  I wonder if this answer was satisfactory in resolving your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```php
^(?=.{8,9}$)[NVQWST][A-Z\s]{1,3}[0-9]{1,6}(?:(?<=^.{8})[A-Z])?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C0pNDw/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?=.{8,9}$)` - the string should contain 8 or 9 chars (other than line break chars, but the pattern won't match them)
- `[NVQWST]` - `N`, `V`, `Q`, `W`, `S` or `T`
- `[A-Z\s]{1,3}` - one, two or three uppercase letters or whitespace
- `[0-9]{1,6}` - one to six digits
- `(?:(?<=^.{8})[A-Z])?` - an optional occurrence of an uppercase ASCII letter if it is the ninth character in a string
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Do you really need both lookaheads? Doesn't the second one ensure that it's 8 or 9 total length?

Comment: @Barmar If you do not use the *lookbehind* at the end, `NABC123A` will get matched.

Comment: I was suggesting that the lookahead at the beginning is redundant.

Comment: But I just tried what I was thinking and it doesn't work. I thought you had `[A-Z]?` in the lookbehind.

Comment: @Barmar You need both the lookahead and the lookbehind. `[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{1,6}` may match just two chars.

Answer (score 2):

Based on rules and details pulled from these links:

- https://www.ppaonline.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/DVA-number-format-factsheet.pdf
- https://meteor.aihw.gov.au/content/339127

I've crafted a comprehensive and strict regex to validate Australian DVA numbers.

```
$regex = <<<REGEX
/
^
([NVQWST])
(?|
  ([ ANPVX])(\d{1,6})

  |(
     BG
    |CN
    |ET
    |F[RW]
    |G[RW]
    |I[QTV]
    |JA
    |K[MO]
    |MO
    |N[FGKX]
    |P[KOX]
    |R[DMU]
    |S[AELMORS]
    |U[BS]
    |YU
  )(\d{1,5})

  |(
    (?:A(?:FG|GX|LX|R[GX])
      |B(?:A[GL]|CG|G[GKX]|RX|U[GRX])
      |C(?:AM|CG|HX|IX|LK|N[KSX]|ON|YP|Z[GX])
      |D(?:EG|N[KX])
      |E(?:G[GXY]|SX|T[KX])
      |F(?:I[JX]|R[GKX])
      |G(?:HA|R[EGKX])
      |H(?:K[SX]|L[GKX]|UX)
      |I(?:DA|ND|SR|T[GKX])
      |K(?:OS|SH|UG|YA)
      |L(?:AX|BX|XK)
      |M(?:A[LRU]|LS|OG|TX|WI)
      |N(?:BA|CG|GR|IG|RD|S[MSW]|W[GKX])
      |OMG
      |P(?:A[DGLMX]|C[AGRV]|H[KSX]|L[GX]|MS|S[MW]|WO)
      |QAG
      |R(?:DX|U[GX])
      |S(?:A[GX]|CG|EG|IN|PG|UD|W[KP]|Y[GRX])
      |T(?:H[KS]|R[GK]|ZA)
      |U(?:AG|RX|S[GKSX])
      |V(?:EX|NS)
      |Y(?:EM|GX)
      |ZIM
    )
  )(\d{1,4})
)
([A-Z]?)
$
/x
REGEX;
```

The first character signifies the state/territory.

- `N` = New South Wales (includes Austalian Capital Territory)
- `V` = Victoria
- `Q` = Queensland
- `W` = Western Australia
- `S` = South Australia (includes Northern Territory)
- `T` = Tasmania

My pattern intentionally uses "branch reset" capture groups so that the match array can be easily used to pad the inner "file number" with leading digits when desired.

Here is [a demo with sample DVA strings, a `preg_match()` call, and zero-padding of the file number to represent full length format](https://3v4l.org/mLpcZ).

If your application requires the DVAs to be zero padded to 8 or 9 characters, then [this is a tighter pattern](https://3v4l.org/HiIHc) to enforce that.

<sub>Yes, I did this all on my phone.

No, I didn't type it all out maually.

I scraped the one webpage and [used regex](https://3v4l.org/IVSpD) to format the content into array syntax for my lookup array.

Then I [compacted the war code abbreviations into groups and character classes](https://3v4l.org/8ECVS).</sub>

Comment: I am not an Australian veteran of war, I've never seen a real DVA card. If I've misunderstood the format, please let me know how, so that I can improve this answer.